# How to validate md-select in angular material 2?

Tags: html, angular, validation, input, angular-material2

everyone.

I am developing app with angular and I am using Angular material for UI.

I know about angular validation

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html

How can I validate `md-select` ?

Comment: it is `md-select` not `m-select` just saying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate md-select the same way it's shown in the documentation. The main idea is to create a reference `#someName` and the use that reference to do the validation. There are six controls that Angular provides: touched, untouched, dirty, pristine, valid and invalid.

I created a Plunker [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/MXvrumvS5tfLW3okwFlL?p=preview) for you with the `dirty` validation for `md-select`.

You can read more about validation in the "Track control state and validity with ngModel" section, here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html